# Spring Security upload file

Tags: java, spring-security, fileupload

Есть проблема, когда я загружаю некоторые файлы, с помощью multipartfile, то получаю "Access is denied".

config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(sessionFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/login",
                    "/registration",
                    "/resources/**",
                    "/error/*",
                    "/language",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/ru/**",
                    "/en/**",
                    "/ua/**"
            )
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
}
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/libs/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadLibFile(
        @RequestParam MultipartFile file,


  HttpServletRequest request
) throws IOException {
    fileService.uploadLibFile(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), file);
    return "redirect:" + getPathWithLocale("admin/libs/general");
}
```

jsp:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/${pageContext.response.locale}/admin/libs/upload" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input name="file" type="file">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload files">
    </p>
</form>
```

В чем проблема, не могу разобраться.

Comment: Разве требуется аутентификация для загрузки файлов, и что значит некоторые?

Comment: В том то и дело, что не должно требоваться, но я находил информацию, что такая проблема есть и связана с MultipartFilter

Comment: Что будет если поменять тип контента, то будет пропускать?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду сontent-type?